# XPS-L421X - Drivers

Tags: dell, xps

anyone know how to install the notebook drivers DELL XPS 14 and your video card NVIDIA Geforce 630 ? I've tried installing the video card, I screwed the whole system had to reinstall. Help me please

Answer (score 0):

The latest NIVIDIA drivers can be downloaded from the xorg-edgers repository

```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

and the other drivers should be installed automatically.